# How can I determine when all child components have completed OnInitializedAsync()?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a dashboard page with 4 - 7 child components (some are not included via `@if(...){ ... }` if the user is not an admin).

I want to put up a single loading... circle over the entire page while all the child components are loading. The main page has 3 lines of code in its `OnInitializedAsync` so that is done and returned before the children are even started.

I can give each child an event in the parent to call when they complete `OnInitializedAsync` and when I receive that event the 4 - 7 times, then hide the loading overlay. But I'm not wild on this approach as it requires I get the count of children execatly right for every combination of user rights on every page. In other words, I'll make a mistake somewhere.

I would also like to use the for my bUnit tests to `WaitFor()` until the page is fully rendered. But this is a nice to have as in the unit tests I can just wait for the bottom-most element to render.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on this to begin with. I get a deja-vu sense that you've asked this again, and I answered again that in React and Blazor, data flows downwards through data binding while events flow upwards through callbacks. If you do that, the root component doesn't have to care what the child components do. They'll say so when they've finished, eg in a `Loaded` event

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.  I suggested DavidThielen ask a new question based on his comments to my answer to his original.  He was asking about coding a `Loaded` event.  DavidThielen - do you want to change the title?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Happy to change the title - what do you suggest it be? TIA

Comment: No one is clamouring for a close, so don't worry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to design for this to happen.  This functionality isn't built in.

The following code uses the registration pattern used in components such a `QuickGrid` where the wrapper component cascades a registration `Action`.  In this example the sub-components register a `Task` which the wrapper component can wait on.

The Overlay component wrapper component for all the components you want to wait on.

```cs
<div class="@_css">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-warning m-5 p-5">
            We are experiencing very high call volumes today [nothing out if the norm now].
            You are at call position 999.  Your business, not you, is important to us!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@if (this.ChildContent is not null)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="Register">
        @this.ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
}
@code {
    private string _css => _isLoading ? "loading" : "loaded";
    private readonly List<Task> _loadingTasks = new();

    private bool _isLoading { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _isLoading = true;

        // Yield so that subcomponents can be first rendered
        await Task.Yield();

        //At this point anyone that wants to will have registered a loading task which will be running
        // So we can await the completion of all of them before we complete and drop the loading banner
        await Task.WhenAll(_loadingTasks);

        // Clean up
        _loadingTasks.Clear();
        _isLoading = false;
    }

    public void Register(Task loadingTask)
    {
        _loadingTasks.Add(loadingTask);
    }
}
```

And Css.  I've set the overlay opacity to 50% so you can see what's going on in the background.

```css
div.loading {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

div.loaded {
    display: none;
}
```

To make this work you need to add some functionality to the sub components.  I've added that to a new base component.  This overrides `SetParametersAsync`.  It creates a `TaskCompletionSource`, picks up cascaded method and registers it's associated Task before starting the lifecycle process. It sets the `TaskCompletionSource` to completed when the lifecycle completes.

```cs
public class LoadingComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter] private Action<Task>? Registration { get; set; }

    private TaskCompletionSource? _registrationTaskCompletionSource;
    private bool _firstRenderCycle = true;

    public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        
        if (Registration is not null && _firstRenderCycle)
        {
            _registrationTaskCompletionSource = new();
            Registration(_registrationTaskCompletionSource.Task);
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);

        if (_firstRenderCycle && _registrationTaskCompletionSource is not null)
        {
            _registrationTaskCompletionSource.SetResult();
            _firstRenderCycle = false;
            _registrationTaskCompletionSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a test sub-component.

```cs
@inherits LoadingComponentBase
<h3>TestComponent</h3>
@if(_loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> Loading </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-success"> Loaded </div>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public int Delay { get; set; } = 1;

    private bool _loading;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        await Task.Delay(Delay);
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

And finally a demo page:

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<LoadingOverlay>

    <TestComponent Delay="1000" />

    <TestComponent Delay="5000" />

    <TestComponent Delay="500" />

</LoadingOverlay>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

I think I've got all the logic right, but if anyone spots a problem, please comment.

[image]

#### Additional answers to questions in the comments.

*Question 1.*

Show me the MS document that says `Task.Yield()` will change?  If it concerns you, use Task.Delay(1);  The purpose of the Delay/Yield is to let all the subcomponents run an initial render, and thus register.

`Task.Yield` creates a continuation of the code following the call that is "posted" to the end of the execution queue. That's all we need as it's beyond the Renderer servicing it's queue.  It creates and calls `SetParametersAsync` on each sub-component: which registers them.

Why not?  The code is not JSInterop, mutates the state of the component (requiring another render), and may not happen early enough.  See my previous comments on `OnAfterRender` being a UI Event, not Lifecycle code.

*Question 2*

You want to register before any render event occurs.  Consider the following code from a component that inherits from `LoadingComponentBase`.

You may well only register after everything else has completed.

```cs
    protected async override Task OnInitilizedAsync()
    {
        await GetSomeVerySlowDataAsync()

        await base.OnIntializedAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping for something a lot easier. Oh well... this works. Thanks.

Comment: Components are loosely coupled.  There are disadvantages as well as advantages with that model.  You also need to keep that model is mind when building components.  I've been  down a ,few blind alleys when I've not respected that.

Comment: Q1: Instead of calling Task.Yield(), wouldn't it be better to put the WhenAll() in OnAfterRenderAsync? As I understand it, the Yield() approach works but is not guaranteed to work in the future while placing this in OnAfterRenderAsync is guaranteed to work. ???

Comment: Q2: Why registering in SetParametersAsync instead of OnInitializationAsync? Is it because SetParametersAsync is called first and OnInitializationAsync might be too late to be registered before the wrapper calls WhenAll? TIA

Comment: See added comment to answer.  You can structure your code as you wish, it's your code.  [Polite] You do keep asking the same questions as to why you shouldn't run xyz code in `OnAfterRender` and I keep giving you the same answer :-)  That may not be a universal view, but I stick to it [and preach it].  You can search my whole codebase: with almost no exceptions, the only calls to `OnAfterRender{Async}` contain JsInterop.

Comment: I've discussed the `OnAfterRender` with numerous people, in part because I highly respect your opinion. And from that I concluded that the safe approach is to only access `@ref=` properties in `OnAfterRender` (or later). We disagree there. With that said, I hope that some day [the Blazor team answers this question authoritatively](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/50819). But in the meantime I'm taking the safe approach.

Comment: Q2.2: In your `OnInitializedAsync()` you call `base.OnIntializedAsync()` as the last call. I call it first figuring I should get any base processing complete before my sub class executes its code. Is there a reason why you put it last? TIA

Comment: It depends on what the base is doing.  That's why I put code in base components in `SetParametersAsync` [as I have above].  You don't need to call the base `OnInitialized{Async}`/ `OnParametersSet{Async}`: there's no base component code in them!  In my own code I'm also strict about inheritance.  No big inheritance trees.  Framework Base -> Application Base -> Sealed Usage.   I use `sealed` a lot.